# Google Healthcare API: how to get Pub/Sub notification when DICOM instance is deidentified

Tags: node.js, google-healthcare-api, google-cloud-healthcare

I am working on Cloud Run service which call API to deidentify a DICOM store.
In my code I did following (using node.js library API):

1. Create a "destination DICOM store" with a specific Pub/Sub topic "InstanceDeidentifiedEvent" for notification by calling API "healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.create" with "notificationConfig" parameter.
2. Then call API "healthcare.projects.locations.datasets.dicomStores.deidentify" to deidentify a source DICOM store. Above "destination DICOM store" is used to store deidentified DICOM instances.

After "deidentify()" API call succeeded and deidentified DICOM instances added to "destination DICOM store", I expect that "Google Healthcare Service" will publish a notification to the Pub/Sub topic "InstanceDeidentifiedEvent", but nothing happened.

So the Pub/Sub notification does not work in this scenario?

Based on google doc: https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/concepts/pubsub, it seems that Pub/Sub notification ONLY works when using "dicomStores.dicomWeb.studies.storeInstances" request to store a DICOM instance. If this is true, then is there any way we can get notification from "destination DICOM store" in above scenario?

I would like to get confirmation form some expert as soon as possible. Thanks a lot for help in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

The ability to send Pub/Sub notifications for bulk writes to a DICOM store is controlled by the (currently) v1beta1 feature `sendForBulkImport` on the `NotificationConfig` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/NotificationConfig)). However, it looks like this property may not be performing as expected in my testing. You can try filing an issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:1138369) to request that `sendForBulkImport` support DeID as well.

Comment: Hi, Nik: Thanks a lot for your quick response! I also did test with v1beta1 API and "sendForBulkImport" to true when creating destination DICOM store, no Pub/Sub notification sent. I will file an issue to request this support in node.js lib.